# Issues Adding Data to an XML Document w/PowerShell

Tags: powershell, xml

Trying to add an element to an existing XML file using PowerShell.  I have looked at several examples and my 'add' script works but, it is misplacing the element.

Sample of XML I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config version="" id="" rev="" marker="">
  <plugins>
    <local>
      <plugin class="LDAPPlugin">
        <config version="0.2">
          <users>
            <search>
              <priority>1</priority>
              <suspended>false</suspended>
              <scope>ALL</scope>
              <orgName>AdmOrg</orgName>
              <filter>LDAPFilter1</filter>
            </search>
          </users> 
        </config>
      </plugin>
    </local>
  </plugins>
</config>
```

I want to add an additional `<search></search>` element to the above XMl file.  Using this code, I have been half way successful:

```
$xmlPath = "C:\productionXML.xml"
$userSearchFilter = "C:\inputData.csv"
$doc = [XML](Get-Content -Path $xmlPath)
foreach($e in (Import-Csv -Path $userSearchFilter))
{
    [STRING]$count = $doc.config.plugins.local.plugin.config.users.search.Count + 1
    $element = $doc.config.plugins.local.plugin.config.users.search[0].clone()
    $element.priority = $count
    $element.suspended = $e.userSuspended
    $element.scope = $e.userScope
    $element.orgName = $e.userOrgMappingAttribute
    $element.filter = $e.userFilter
    $doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild($element)
}
$doc.Save("C:\newProductionXML.xml")
```

When I execute the script, the element is added but, to the bottom of the XML, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config version="" id="" rev="" marker="">
  <plugins>
    <local>
      <plugin class="LDAPPlugin">
        <config version="0.2">
          <users>
            <search>
              <priority>1</priority>
              <suspended>false</suspended>
              <scope>ALL</scope>
              <orgName>AdmOrg</orgName>
              <filter>LDAPFilter1</filter>
            </search>
          </users> 
        </config>
      </plugin>
    </local>
  </plugins>
</config>
<search>
  <priority>1</priority>
  <suspended>false</suspended>
  <scope>ALL</scope>
  <orgName>AdmOrg</orgName>
  <filter>NewLDAPFilter</filter>
</search>
```

I have ran this code against "less complicated" XML files and it does exactly what it is supposed to then but, when I run it against the XML I need it to, it places the additional element at the root of the XML file.  Please forgive my lack of exact language with respect to XML, I do not often work with XML in this manner.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245359/how-to-add-a-child-element-for-xml-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems you're running into here. First, since there is only one `<search>` element at first, the `search` property won't be a collection. To fix that, we can use `GetElementsByTagName` to make sure we always get a collection. Replace the first two lines of the for loop with these:

```
$searchElements = $doc.config.plugins.local.plugin.config.users.GetElementsByTagName('search')
[STRING]$count = $searchElements.Count + 1
$element = $searchElements[0].Clone()
```

Second and more relevant to the question itself, `AppendChild` on the `DocumentElement` will tack the element on to the main document. You want to add it to the `<users>` tag, so we call `AppendChild` on the `users` property. Replace the last line of the for loop with this:

```
$doc.config.plugins.local.plugin.config.users.AppendChild($element) | Out-Null
```

The `Out-Null` is just there to stop the newly appended item from being echoed to the console.